# What would make one brick wall harder than another?

Tags: climbing, climbing-grades

Inspired mostly by this [question](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/6174/brick-wall-rating), where a person was asking what the climbing rating of a brick wall was.

Compared to all of the varied climbs in nature with the many different rock features and types, brick walls seem like they would be much more uniform (especially in vertical angle) and have to be built to certain standards.

What would make one brick wall harder to climb than the next?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think there is an (international) standard for making brick walls or even bricks. While it's true that (most) brick walls have a 90 degrees angle, all the other features can be fairly different.

Here is a list of just a few things that can differ in between brick walls:

- size of bricks
- texture of bricks (rough, smooth)
- amount of mortar in between bricks
- how well the gaps between bricks are filled with mortar
- any wall damages/ cracks/ brick parts missing

That's just from the top of my head, I am sure wall experts or experienced wall climbers could name a few more. (:

Comment: Why should a brick wall be rated differently from a natural wall?  Artificial walls in a climbing gym use the standard rating system.  Rate it on difficulty to climb not features.

Comment: where did I say routes on brick walls cannot be graded with the same grades as routes in climbing gyms or on a rock? I just answered a question why not all brick walls are equal and therefore can actually be graded (;

Comment: All of the things mentioned in this answer are things that would affect the grade.  There is nothing to suggest using a special "brick wall grading system."